# Local time to EST time Conversion

Tags: android, date, timezone, simpledateformat

Android Local time to EST time Conversion

Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat serverDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
serverDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
Calendar calender= Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
String  time=serverDateFormat.format(calender.getTime());
```

but i getting **wrong time.** 
one hour difference from right time. 
for eg : 
local time : Tue Jul 07 17:30:00 GMT+05:30 2015
formated time : 2015/07/07 07:00:00
right time   :  2015/07/07 08:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is using the identifier "EST" which stands for "Eastern Standard Time". As the name suggests it does not use daylight saving rules. Proof:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
long offset = tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()) / (1000 * 3600);
System.out.println(tz.getID() + ":" + tz.useDaylightTime() + "/" + offset);
// output: EST:false/-5
```

Use the timezone id "America/New_York" instead:

```
tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
offset = tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()) / (1000 * 3600);
System.out.println(tz.getID() + ":" + tz.useDaylightTime() + "/" + offset);
// output: America/New_York:true/-4
```

Then you will observe daylight saving time in July making an offset difference of (+05:30) - (-04:00) = +09:30 resulting in the expected local time 8 AM.

Comment: how to use this offset to get exact UTC -0 datetime??

Comment: can u please explain this with proper example?

Comment: @VishalHalani Usually you don't need to do offset calculations. If you have `java.util.Date` or longs as millisecs since unix epoch then it is already UTC. But the offset is indirectly used within `SimpleDateFormat` for conversions between local date display and an object of type `java.util.Date`. If you want to interprete a local timestamp as UTC then simply set the zone to "GMT" or "UTC" on `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I was convert datetime to UTC-0 London timezone so its make -5:30 from time  now when i insert that in sharepoint it show +1 hour in UTC-0 time. mean if i am adding 7.30 utc time then there i can see 8.30 entry

Comment: @VishalHalani Your comment is not clear for me. I suggest you to open a new question on SO with short, complete and compilable example and showing your input and output and what you have expected instead. It seems maybe even Microsoft Sharepoint is involved in your issue which is something quite different (even outside of Java).

Comment: Thanks I was Solved problem I get Problem because in sharepoint London take UTC-0 where in android its take +1 timezone so it create problem

Answer (score -1):

hey please try this `function` for time `conversion` -

```
    public static String getTime(String time, SimpleDateFormat sdf) {
    String convertedTime = "";

    try {
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Date postdate = sdf.parse(time);
        long postTimeStamp = postdate.getTime() + timeZone.getRawOffset();

        String dateString = sdf.format(new Date(postTimeStamp));

        convertedTime = dateString;


        // convertedTime = getLastTime(context, time);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertedTime;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why OP should do this instead of what is he doing currently?

Comment: @Prerak - he can modify my function but as per my requirement, there were so many date format & why we become dependent over server time zone.