# Android Calendar does not show start of day, 00:00:00

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to create a Calendar object for the start of the day, or 00:00:00

Here is my code.

```
    val calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"), Locale.US)
    calendarStart.time = Date()
    calendarStart[Calendar.HOUR] = 0
    calendarStart[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 0
    calendarStart[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
    calendarStart[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
    calendarStart[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
    val utcStartDate = calendarStart.time

    val calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"), Locale.US)
    calendarEnd[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 23
    calendarEnd[Calendar.MINUTE] = 59
    calendarEnd[Calendar.SECOND] = 59
    calendarEnd[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 999
    val utcEndDate = calendarEnd.time
```

The end date seems ok, but the start date shows as 01:00:00 as seen in the screenshot of the debugger log.

Can someone explain to me why it show as 1:00:00 and how do I create a start of day calendar?

[image]

*** **UPDATE** ***

The answer #snachmsm gave was correct and did solve the issue.  However, I opted to use this code instead:

```
    val dayStart: LocalDateTime = now.with(LocalTime.MIN)
    val zdtStart: ZonedDateTime = dayStart.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val startDate = Date.from(zdtStart.toInstant())

    val dayEnd: LocalDateTime = now.with(LocalTime.MAX)
    val zdtEnd: ZonedDateTime = dayEnd.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    val endDate = Date.from(zdtEnd.toInstant())
```

Comment: what value are you trying to start the calendar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that you are trying to get `EST` timezone and log shows `EDT` timezone - 1h of difference like in your case

according to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268500/local-time-to-est-time-conversion) `EST` in Android doesn't use daylight saving. try to use `getTimeZone("America/New_York")`

Comment: LOL! Yes, DUH... my BAD.  And YES, that did correct the issue.  However, I ended up doing this:

  val dayStart: LocalDateTime = now.with(LocalTime.MIN)
  val zdtStart: ZonedDateTime = dayStart.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  val startDate = Date.from(zdtStart.toInstant())

  val dayEnd: LocalDateTime = now.with(LocalTime.MAX)
  val zdtEnd: ZonedDateTime = dayEnd.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  val endDate = Date.from(zdtEnd.toInstant())